# Create valid CRM 2016 Alternate Keys

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm currently able to successfully create Alternate Keys in my Plugin by passing in string values.  However, when I try to generate one for 'opportunityproduct' using 'productdescription', I get an error.  Attempting to create one through the UI shows me that 'productdescription' is not an available attribute for usage even though it is a string field.

Is there a way through the Web API to figure out which string, decimal, or integer fields are available to use in an Alternate Key?  I don't see anything under entity definitions or their related attributes

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: It was specific for CRM Javascript and utilizing the Web API since there's currently not much of a point to use it in the plugins at the moment, I can see how the tag isn't quite useful though. I'll remove.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [Single line strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn932139.aspx) are valid for Alternate Keys.  ProductDescription is a single line string, so I'd submit a ticketto microsoft as to why you can't.